# Definite integral of nth root of quadratic

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I want to show that the following holds:
$$\int_0^1(1-x^2)^\frac{1}{n}\,dx=\frac{n}{n+1}$$
I'm clueless as to how to approach the problem (after considering possible substitutions, expansions, etc.) and would appreciate any hints.

Comment: But it's false!

Comment: It fails at least for $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: For $n=2$ this is one fourth the area of the unit circle, hence $\frac {\pi}4$.

Comment: The formula is correct if $x^2$ is replaced by $x$. Is that what you meant?

Comment: The integral I started with was $$\frac{1}{2R}\int_{-R}^{R}(1-\frac{x^2}{R^2})^\frac{1}{n}\,dx$$, which I simplified to the one above. Perhaps I made a mistake in the simplification then, although I don't see it. I made the substitution $$ x = \frac{x'}{R}$$ and adjusted the limits accordingly.

Comment: @fizicar Here is the [answer to your original integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+x%3D-R+to+x%3DR+of+1%2F(2R)*(1-x%5E2%2FR%5E2)%5E(1%2Fn)dx) and here is the [answer to the simplified integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+x%3D0+of+x%3D1+of+(1-x%5E2)%5E(1%2Fn)). As you can see, they both yield the same answer, so you were correct in your simplification. Why did you expect the answer of $\frac{n}{n+1}$?

Comment: I was asked to show this as an exercise, although the integrand which gives  this answer was also in the text so I assume it was a typo. I should've checked the simple cases of n to begin with. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you meant $\int_0^1 (1-x)^{1/n}dx=\frac{n}{n+1}$ because the formula in your question is incorrect, but this formula is correct.

Now, first, we want to use $u$-substitution in order to get the integral in terms of $u=1-x$. Thus, we have $dx=-du$ and the bounds change from $0 \to 1$ to $1 \to 0$, so we get:
$$\int_1^0 -u^{1/n}du=\int_0^1 u^{1/n}du$$

Now, we just use power rule to take the integral. Notice that the power is $1+\frac 1 n=\frac{n+1}{n}$, so the coefficient of the integral is the reciprocal, which is $\frac{n}{n+1}$:
$$\left[\frac{n}{n+1}u^{1+1/n}\right]^1_0$$

Direct substitution shows that this is $\frac{n}{n+1}$.